# Polymerfire: 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication for my application authentication, but I get a `Cannot read property 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined` error.

Below follows the code.

**index.html**

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>ProcWeb</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My App description">

    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3f51b5">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android. Fallback for manifest.json -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="application-name" content="My App">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="My App">

    <!-- Homescreen icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/manifest/icon-48x48.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/manifest/icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="/images/manifest/icon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/images/manifest/icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="/images/manifest/icon-192x192.png">

    <!-- Tile icon for Windows 8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/images/manifest/icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3f51b5">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

    <script>
      // Setup Polymer options
      window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow',
        lazyRegister: true
      };

      // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
      (function() {
        'use strict';

        var onload = function() {
          // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
          // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
          if (!window.HTMLImports) {
            document.dispatchEvent(
              new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
            );
          }
        };

        var webComponentsSupported = (
          'registerElement' in document
          && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
          && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );

        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.async = true;
          script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
          script.onload = onload;
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        } else {
          onload();
        }
      })();

      // Load pre-caching Service Worker
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        });
      }
    </script>

    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-elements.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body unresolved>

  <!-- Configure Service Worker caching: -->
  <platinum-sw-register
      auto-register
      skip-waiting
      clients-claim
      reload-on-install
      href="/service-worker.js">
    <platinum-sw-cache
        default-cache-strategy="networkFirst">
    </platinum-sw-cache>
  </platinum-sw-register>

    <!-- Configure Firebase app: -->
    <firebase-app
            name="procWeb"
            apiKey="AIzaSyDA-JuUnKmucXk3VXMhk4r8CYihSELQyAA"
            authDomain="procweb-28a01.firebaseapp.com"
            databaseUrl="https://procweb-28a01.firebaseio.com">
    </firebase-app>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <!-- Built with love using Polymer Starter Kit -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**my-app.html**

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<!--<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">-->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;

        display: block;
      }

      app-header {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
      }
      app-header paper-icon-button {
        --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
      }

      .drawer-list {
        margin: 0 20px;
      }

      .drawer-list a {
        display: block;

        padding: 0 16px;

        text-decoration: none;

        color: var(--app-secondary-color);

        line-height: 40px;
      }

      .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
        color: black;

        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style> 

    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer>
        <app-toolbar>ProcWeb</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
          <a name="view1" href="/view1">Home</a>
          <a name="view1" href="/view1">Gestão de Clientes</a>
          <a name="view2" href="/view2">Gestão de Processos</a>
          <a name="view3" href="/view3">Agenda</a>
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>ProcWeb</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <!-- Configure Firebase app: -->
        <!--<firebase-app
                name="procWeb"
                apiKey="AIzaSyDA-JuUnKmucXk3VXMhk4r8CYihSELQyAA"
                authDomain="procweb-28a01.firebaseapp.com"
                databaseUrl="https://procweb-28a01.firebaseio.com"
                storageBucket="procweb-28a01.appspot.com"
                messagingSenderId="621427834965">
        </firebase-app>-->
        <firebase-auth 
          id="auth"
          app-name="procWeb"
          user="{{user}}"
          on-error="showError">
        </firebase-auth>

        <div hidden$="[[user]]" class="card">
          <h3>Email/Password</h3>
          <form on-submit="signInWithEmailAndPassword">
            <paper-input label="Email" type="email" value="{{email}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Password" type="password" value="{{password}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-button type="submit" on-tap="signIn" raised class="custom indigo">Sign In</paper-button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div hidden$="[[!user]]">
          <iron-pages
            selected="[[page]]"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="view404"
            role="main">
          <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
          <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
          <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
          <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
        </iron-pages>
        </div>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
 (function() {
      'use strict';

    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged'
        }
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      },
      signIn: function() {
        // firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(function(response){
        //   this.page = 'view1';
        // }).catch(function(error){
        //   console.log(error);
        // });
        this.$.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(function(response){

        }).catch(function(error){

        });
      }
    });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm using Polymer 1.0 and Firebase 3.0.
Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: try taking out the form tag.  but it still won't work because this.email and this.password will be undefined as they are not properties of your element.

Comment: Hi @RyanTyler, thanks but it didn't work.

Comment: I've basically only got this to work by copying over the firebase-app element into every iron-page. Didn't find a proper solution to this yet